# Google chart doesnt load with javascript on Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, charts, google-visualization

I am relatively new to google charts and was trying to run a basic chart for demo and further development.

Its a pretty basic script and was working well till yesterday and now it doesnt load anything.

I am loading this script in script editor webpart of Sharepoint and trying to load it. Not sure if its my case or just that Google Charts has a problem.

Pl help. Am I missing something conceptual here? Its a pretty basic code that I got from http://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/visualizing-sharepoint-google-charts/ and modified it a bit for my use.

I have run window.alert and it is extracting all values in the enumerator correctly. I think then something happens and the chart doesnt load.

javascript alerts also pop up after the barChart.draw(data, options), and lineChart.draw(data, options) code part, so the code has execute fully.

Thank you 
Niraj

```
*<html> 
<head> 
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var returnedItems = null; 
function loadGoogleLibAndDraw(){
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar','line']});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(visualizeData);
}
function visualizeData() { 
 var context = new SP.ClientContext(); 
 var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(document.getElementById('customListName').value); 
 var caml = new SP.CamlQuery(); 
 caml.set_viewXml("<View></View>"); 
 returnedItems = list.getItems(caml); 
 context.load(returnedItems); 
 context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback); 
} 
function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) { 
 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 data.addColumn('string', 'Part No');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Volume');
 var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator(); 
 var markup = ''; 
 while (enumerator.moveNext()) { 
 var row = [];

 var listItem = enumerator.get_current(); 
 row.push(listItem.get_item('Part_x0020_No'));
 row.push(listItem.get_item('Volume'));
 data.addRow(row);

 } 

var options = {
 chart: {
 title: 'KPIs',
 },
 bars: 'vertical' 
 };

 var barChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('BarChart'));
 barChart.draw(data, options);
 var lineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('LineChart'));
 lineChart.draw(data, options);
} 

function onFailedCallback(sender, args) { 
 var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>'; 
 markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>'; 
 displayDiv.innerHTML = markup; 
}
</script>
</head> 

<body onload="loadGoogleLibAndDraw()"> 
 <form name="metricsform" id="metricsform">
 <input id="customListName" name="customListName" value="Projects" type="hidden"/>
 </form>
 <div> 
 <div id="displayDiv"></div>
 <div id="BarChart" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
 <div id="LineChart" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
 </div> 
</body> 
</html>*
```

Comment: Nope, the page loads perfectly - all webparts other than the sharepoint script editor loads seamlessly and a blank screen loads as a part of the screen whether the editor webpart is placed.

Comment: Hi, I check and reload the page again after a day of frustration and see that it is loading on its own! If google charts is this unreliable that it loads on whims and fancies, it might be difficult to use in a serious setting.

Comment: Anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score 0):

recommend **not** using inline tag events --> `<body onload="...`

especially if there are multiple editor web parts / `<body>` tags

also, it isn't necessary since the [loader](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#Callback)...
*will wait for the document to finish loading before calling the callback*

to be absolute sure, place all `<script>` tags at the bottom, just before the `</body>` end tag

recommend following setup...

```
<html>
<body>
  <form name="metricsform" id="metricsform">
    <input id="customListName" name="customListName" value="Projects" type="hidden"/>
  </form>
  <div>
    <div id="displayDiv"></div>
    <div id="BarChart" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
    <div id="LineChart" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var returnedItems = null;
  function visualizeData() {
   var context = new SP.ClientContext();
   var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(document.getElementById('customListName').value);
   var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
   caml.set_viewXml("<View></View>");
   returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);
   context.load(returnedItems);
   context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);
  }
  function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Part No');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Volume');
    var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();
    var markup = '';
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
      var row = [];

      var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
      row.push(listItem.get_item('Part_x0020_No'));
      row.push(listItem.get_item('Volume'));
      data.addRow(row);
    }

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'KPIs',
      },
      bars: 'vertical'
    };

    var barChart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('BarChart'));
    barChart.draw(data, options);
    var lineChart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('LineChart'));
    lineChart.draw(data, options);
  }
  function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {
    var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';
    markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';
    displayDiv.innerHTML = markup;
  }
  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: visualizeData,
    packages: ['bar', 'line']
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello WhiteHat, Thank you for your response. I will try this and come back in a day or two to ensure that it works always :) Thank you! Niraj